# SystemClock.sleep() blocks test after some time

Tags: android-uiautomator

Just started with UiAutomator for testing some gaming app. Since I cannot work with real UI elements I work with clicks and swipes directly, which works fine.

For the process I need some sleeps and tried SystemClock.sleep(), which is internally used as well.

After some swipes and sleeps the whole test is getting blocked.

What I found it could be some threading issues. But didn't find any solution for this.

What is the right approach for what I described?

Comment: Show the code you are using.

Comment: @U.Windl I started with an UiAutomator example and reduced to the basics. In `@Before` function I just load the instance with `mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(getInstrumentation());`

In one `@Test` I do several clicks and swipes like:

`mDevice.click(80, 80); SystemClock.sleep(500); mDevice.swipe(100, 400, 100, 800, 20); SystemClock.sleep(500);`

Test runs for a while. Then it blocks. Actually, I just waited and after about 40 minutes the test continued.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comments if it's essential for the question to understand. Despite of that I thing the details given are not enough for others to help.